# Почему некоторые файлы не проходят валидацию при загрузке на сервер, и почему при этом не выдаётся ошибка?

Tags: yii2, валидация, mp3

Система: `Yii2, Windows 10`.

Правило валидации загрузки аудио файлов:

```
public function rules()
{
    return [
        [['audioFile'], 'file', 'extensions' => 'mp3, m4a', 'skipOnEmpty' => false],
    ];
}

public function upload()
{
    if ($this->validate()) {
        $this->audioFile->saveAs('m_upload/audio/' . $this->audioFile->baseName . '.' . $this->audioFile->extension);
        return true;
    } else {
        return false;
    }
}
```

Заметил, что некоторые mp3 - файлы проходят валидацию и загружаются на сервер, а некоторые не проходят. Во втором случае ошибку в форме я не получаю, страница просто перезагружается.

Поскольку удаление параметра проверки `extensions` проблему "незагрузки" файлов на сервер снимало, прихожу к выводу, что причина так или иначе связана с конкретными mp3-файлами и/или проверкой на них.

Как таковая валидация работает, при установке в `extensions` произвольного значения, например, `aaamp3`, уведомление о несоответствующем формате файла форма выдаёт.

Допустим, файлы как-то повреждены и не проходят валидацию (хотя их корректно обрабатывает аудиоплеер), но почему не выдается ошибка тогда? Кто-то может подсказать, в чем причина такого поведения?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

По умолчанию, при загрузке файла идет проверка соответствия расширения файла, его MIME типу (вроде как exe переименовали в doc и загружают) в файле /validators/FileValidator.php

```
/**
 * @var bool whether to check file type (extension) with mime-type. If extension produced by
 * file mime-type check differs from uploaded file extension, the file will be considered as invalid.
 */
public $checkExtensionByMimeType = true;
```

Можно проверку отключить и указать допустимые MIME типы:

```
 public function rules()
{
    return [
        [['audioFile'], 'file', 'checkExtensionByMimeType' => false, 'extensions' => 'mp3, m4a', 'mimeTypes' => 'audio/*', 'skipOnEmpty' => false],
    ];
}
```

Comment: Насколько это безопасно? И остается главный вопрос: в чем причина такого поведения, можно ли её устранить не понижая уровня безопасности? Почему происходит то, что я наблюдаю?

Comment: Безопасность не пострадает: другое расширение файла не загрузить, кроме audio файлы не загрузить. Можно ограничить MIME строже audio/mpeg, audio/mp3 и т.д.. Проблема с MIME может быть из-за файла, браузера, версии ПО на сервере и ещё большого количества нюансов.

Comment: https://yiiframework.ru/forum/viewtopic.php?t=23110